# Nested json to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, json

i'm having structure of json like given below

```
{
    "today": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "value": 100
    },
    "yesterday": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "value": 90
    }
}
```

and i want to convert it to multi-dimentional array in php like given below:-

```
Array
(
    [today] => Array
        (
            [currencyCode] => USD
            [value] => 100
        )

    [yesterday] => Array
        (
            [currencyCode] => USD
            [value] => 90
        )

)
```

Comment: [`json_decode($json, true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - [Live Example](https://repl.it/repls/OlivedrabDownrightCores)

Answer (score 1):

like this,

```
    $json ='{
    "today": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "value": 100
    },
    "yesterday": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "value": 90
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);


    var_dump($data);
```